# How to return list of user defined data type using Ajax in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, serialization

I am trying to call a getData web method which will return a list of Destination table record (I am using ADO.NET Entity Framework Model) which contain cityID, country, city but I am getting a 500 internal server error. 
if I make a new Destination object  and adding it to a new list then there is no error. What to do please help me, I am a newbie.

[image]

### console error

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

response text: "{"Message":"A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type \u0027System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Dest ......}"

### Open image in new tab

[image]

### .js

```
function getData() {
    return $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "Sandbox3.aspx/getData",
        data: JSON.stringify({}),
        dataType: "json",
    });
}

$('button').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var promise = getData();

    promise.success(showData);
    promise.error(onError);
});
function onError(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
    console.log(xhr);
    alert(xhr.status);
    alert(thrownError);
}

function showData(data) {
    console.log(data.d);
}
```

### .aspx.cs

```
public partial class Sandbox3 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private static HotelDB db = new HotelDB();

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static List<Destination> getData()
    {
        return db.Destinations.ToList();
    }
}
```

### .aspx

```
<body>
<div>
    <form runat="server">
        <button id="box">Go</button>
    </form>
</div>
<script src="scripts/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/ajaxtest.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

With entity framework you most likely have LazyLoading Enabled, disable that and try.  What is most likely happening is, when you try to return the Desitniation object which EF made, it has a tblHotelDetails property, that is causing the issue.  By disabling LazyLoading that property will not populate when you send your object back.  If you need it populated, either create a custom class as you did, or you can disable LazyLoading and use the Include method to bring that property in, though i'm not sure if including it will lead to the same error.

If you want to see the actual error, get Fiddler, run that and then your site, when you get the 500 error, look at Fiddler and you will see the actual error.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit late, but maybe it will help someone else.  For JSON, flatten and pay attention to any navigation properties (assuming an ORM like EntityFramework)...

In your case--the Destination navigation property...  If it's a navigation property, you need to pull out the information (flatten)--e.g., Destination.DestinationName

```
public JsonResult getJson()
{
    return this.Json(
         new {
              Result = (from obj in db.Product select new {Id = obj.Id, Name = obj.Name, obj.Category.Description})
              }
              , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
              );
}
```

Go take a look at the navigation property for Category...  Chances are that you might have something similar to obj.Category, when you may actually intended to have obj.Category.Description or something similar (e.g., obj.Destination.DestinationName)...  Navigation properties usually reference back to the parent again.  JSON serializers don't do so well with understanding those "circular" references.

;-)  I had the same issue a while back and I beat my head on the table when I realized what I had done.